# VBA Cdate to interpret DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of dates that are stored in the DD-MM-YYYY format. I'm looping through them with VBA's cdate function to convert them to values - however, while the day of the month is 12 or smaller, Cdate interprets the date as MM-DD-YYYY. What's the most convenient way around this?

Comment: If your regional settings don't use dd-mm-yyyy format, as appears to be the case, and if the dates are actually stored as text, you'll have to parse the date string yourself.

Comment: If the dates are actually formatted as dates in excel then there would be no reason to pass them to `CDATE()` to convert them. Just set your date variable to the cell value. If they are stored as text, then you have to parse the string with `Mid()` to rearrange it and pass the result to Cdate().

Comment: They arent, they're formatted as text (strings extracted from HTML and then removed tags)

Comment: Split them on the `/` and feed them to the `Dateserial` function.  Or, use the `Data/Text-to-columns` wizard and define the column format as `DMY` (or the equivalent in Power Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `DateSerial` function.Try this:

```
Sub ConvertDate()
Dim datecell As Variant, i As Long

With Workbooks("book1").Sheets(1)
    For i = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        datecell = Split(.Range("A" & i), "/")
        .Range("B" & i) = DateSerial(datecell(2), datecell(1), datecell(0))
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

This assumes your workbook is called "Book1" and the date values are in column A. The results will be written to column B.